# Backbone Events Map not Working

Tags: javascript, events, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I am currently trying to write a model that will simply run a function whenever data is fetched. As far as I am concerned, I am implementing it the correct way but it repeatedly fails to work the way I would expect it to.

At the minute, the model looks like this:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // fetch the data for this, on return, create modela about it
    url: function() {
        return 'api.example.com/users/' + this.id + '/intialisation';
    },
    events: {
        reset: alert('this works')
    },
    makeItems: function() {
        var newItems, currentInitialiser, currentItem;

        alert('this does not');
    }
});
```

Whenever `fetch()` is called on an instance of this, the alert box pops up 'this works' as expected. However, if I change the event map to

```
events: {
    reset: "makeItems"
}
```

or

```
events: {
    reset: this.makeItems
}
```

the function does not run (you DO NOT see the 'this does not work' alert box). Perhaps this is due to my misunderstanding of the way this event map works but I am pretty sure I have seen stuff like this that has worked and I cannot figure out why this does not. I have looked at the backbone docs but they are not very descriptive, however, as far as I understand it, what I have written should work.

Hopefully this won't be too tricky to sort out

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the events hash is used in backbone views, as supported by backbone's [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents).  For a model, you'd want to create a listener using `listenTo`.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // fetch the data for this, on return, create modela about it
    url: function() {
        return 'api.example.com/users/' + this.id + '/intialisation';
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this,'reset',this.makeItems);
    },
    makeItems: function() {
        var newItems, currentInitialiser, currentItem;
        alert('this does not');
    }
});
```

This should point you in the right direction.

EDIT: Also, as per Backbone's documentation, `fetch` on a model doesn't trigger a `reset`. It triggers a `change`. http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch

Comment: That's a very good question. It didn't work for me when I copied your code, except for when I actually defined MyModel.  Instances of MyModel wouldn't fire off the event, however.

Comment: I think I was being stupid. I left the bracket on the end of the `alert` and so the function was actually being invoked with the result being passed into the map.

Comment: is there any good reason why view events are handled differently?

Comment: Because delegateEvents is specifically related to DOM events.  I guess it's a nice way to prevent people from accidentally creating jQuery selectors that aren't confined to elements within $el.  It sure makes things nice and clean, doesn't it?